# GeoPy Geocoder randomly doesn't work, but sometimes does

Tags: python, flask, geocode, geopy, nominatim

I have been using GeoPy with Nominatim perfectly for a couple of days. However, at random times I will receive an error when my app had previously been working a couple of seconds ago. I have implemented this code inside a flask app where you can input a city and get its longitude and latitude.
Here is the error I randomly get when **trying to turn an address into a longitude and latitude value:**

```
GeocoderTimedOut: Service timed out
```

Then after I reload the app, it may begin to work again or it will stick like that for a couple more tries. I have no idea what is occurring here. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Cheers

Comment: Some of these services have a throughput consideration. I had this exact error recently and found out it was because I was submitting too many queries (which I didn't consider exorbitant). Try limiting your number of submissions/minute or so and see if the error disappears.

Comment: Sometimes if I don't use my app for about 30 minutes, the error will still occur. I'm pretty sure I am well within GeoPy's query limit.

Comment: Service timeout isn't mean that address is not correct or it can't be found by the API used?